# Empty space to the right when using W3-card

Tags: css, w3.css

When I use the W3-card class, the right side of the element is not always used.

I have set the padding-right to 0px and still same.

What could be reason.

Code below

```
<div class="w3-content w3-card-4" style="width:500px; padding-right:2px ">
<div class="w3-row">

 <div class="col-md-7">
 <h2 style="color:blue;"> Logged Out </h2>
 <br />
 You have Logged Out Successfully.  You can <a runat="server" class="w3-badge 
 w3-purple w3-hover-blue"  href="~/Login.aspx">Login</a> here
 </div> 
 </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Code added to the question

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Rob.  I wouldn't put it that way: `<br>` is a directive that does not need a closing tag.  Separately, the slash will cause the tag to be unrecognised.  In any case, that is not the question that is asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the use of that class="col-md-7". it is limiting the usage of the other side.

Got it cracked

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.